Initialize a Safe using private key
I am trying to understand the best practices for using the Safe SDK.
I have these lines of code:
async function generateSafeCreationData(owners, threshold) {
const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.init({ provider: RPC_URL, signer: "OxPrivateKey" });

const safeAccountConfig = {
    owners,
    threshold
};
const safeSdk = await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig });

I am planning on running tis piece of code in React Native for a mobile app.
The private key will be stored encrypted at HW level.
The fact that I am passing the private key, to the .init method, isn't a security issue?

It is not a security issue as long as the call is not executed client-side. The SDK makes no API calls directly containing this private key and the use of this data is purely internal. So as long as it is ran on the server, and stored securely (such as in a secure element in the device), it can be considered safe.
Hope it helps; Best, Louis
